# Selenium IDE and custom confirm() function conflict

Tags: jquery, selenium, firefox-addon, selenium-ide, simplemodal

I am using [simple modal dialog](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) by Eric Martin. And have defined a function e.g

```
function confirm(message, options) {....
  }
```

To customize all confirm dialogs. Its working nicely accross all the browsers.Except when I enable Selenium IDE ,my custom confirm dialog function fails to capture "options" parameters and firefox console echos like this:

```
options is undefined callback=options.callback;
```

**Error When Selenium IDE is visible**

[image]

**Normal Behaviour When Selenium IDE is closed**
  [image]

Please help me sort out this issue so I should able to run selenium tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

current possible solution:

It revealed to me that [selenium IDE recorder](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/ide/src/extension/content/recorder.js?r=8284) is also overriding the various functions. Current possible quick way-out from this bug is to rename confirm() function and its references :(